# DBContext Native SQL Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework-5

How to use native queries with `DBContext` ? If I run the code, this give me exception. Why and what to do to run native query when using `DBContext` ?

```
AcademyEntities context = new AcademyEntities();

            string nativeSQLQuery =
                "SELECT * " +
                "FROM dbo.Employees " +
                "WHERE FirstName='{0}'";

            string name = "Guy";

            var emp = context.Departments.SqlQuery(nativeSQLQuery, name);

            foreach (var item in emp)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Try removing the quotes round the {0}

Comment: The exception is "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'TelerikAcademyModel.Department'. A member of the type, 'Name', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Comment: Does the table `Departments` have a `Employees`  in it?

Comment: No, it is in other table. Here is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying the `Employees` table, but trying to materialize `Department` objects.

Change your call to:

```
var emp = context.Employees.SqlQuery(nativeSQLQuery, name);
```

( and remove the quotes round the `{0}` )

Comment: It worked.Thank you.I have one more question. With EF5  "AcademyEntities" inherit DBContext. In previous versions in EF (4.0) "AcademyEntities" inherit ObjectContext. Why in EF5.0 "AcademyEntities" interit DBContext ? Is it better ? What is the difference ?

Comment: @user1749358 excellent :) `DbContext` was introduced in EF 4.1 - most people use it now.

Comment: Is this a good practice to use native sql queries in this way ?

Comment: @user1749358 No, it's not really good practice. You should use LINQ-to-Entities and let EF generate the SQL for you. It's also easier! You can download some samples from [`here`](http://weblogs.aspnet05.orcsweb.com/bschooley/archive/2007/10/25/msdn-s-101-linq-samples.aspx). Also, try out [`LINQPad`](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: What if I have more parametres?

Answer (score 1):

You are querying Employees, so you should use context.Employees:

```
var emp = context.Employees.SqlQuery(nativeSQLQuery, name);
```